# how to write a huge matrix to file row by row (fortran 90)

Tags: matrix, fortran, intel-fortran

I want to write a matrix with a lot of data to a file row by row. For example, I have a matrix 100*100 and I want to have it in form 100*100 in the file. However, it doesn't work.Following is my code and some description. N and M are integers around some hundreds. RECL is expected length I set the file but here it seems this command does not work. The output is with 198 lines when N is set 99
and M is set 200. Vec is a double precision complex matrix. How could I output the values of Vec keeping its original format N*M? My compile command is "ifort -o out test.f90".

```
open(unit=2, file='graph1.txt', ACTION="write", STATUS="replace",RECL=40*M+10)
do i=1,N
 do j=1,M
  write(2, '(F)', advance='no') real(Vec(i,j)) 
 end do
  write(2, *) '' 
end do
```

Following @george advice, I coded a program like this:

```
program test
implicit none

integer i,j

open(unit=2, file='graph1.txt', ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
do i=1,500
 write(2, '(1600F14.7)')( 0.00001 ,j=1,499)
end do

close(2)

end
```

With this code, problem solved! Maybe I didn't compile correctly last time.

Comment: What does it do then? What is "doesn't work"?

Comment: And how is `Vec` declared? I hope you do not try to run your code with different `M` and `N` on 100x100 array?

Comment: you need a repeat specifier in the format.  In older fortran you need an actual number eg. '(1000F14.7)' , where the number is anything bigger than m.  Recent  standards allow a "*" ..  The explicit format with advance = no is going to override whatever you put for recl on open.

Comment: "doesn't work" means when M is over specific number like 200,300, the elements of one row will take 3 lines in file. What I want is row by row like the way it is stored in code. Vec is allocatable array Vec(N,M), so don't worry its legitimacy...

Comment: Mhm, your code works fine with me - for both `gfortran` (4.7.3) and `ifort` (13.1.3). Which version of `ifort` are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

expanding on my comment, you should also use an implicit loop..try this:

```
open(unit=2, file='graph1.txt', ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
do i=1,N
     write(2, '(1000F14.7)')( real(Vec(i,j)) ,j=1,M)
end do
```

or for sufficiently modern compilers (I'm not sure  how new.. )

```
     write(2, '(*(F14.7))')( real(Vec(i,j)) ,j=1,M)
```

Note as has been pointed out, the parenthesis around `(F14.7)` are required for the `*` unlimited-format-item in the 2008 standard.

may as well pull in the other comments, you can also do this:

```
      write(2, '(*(F14.7))')real(Vec(i,:M))
```

Comment: That's the Fortran 2008 *unlimited format item* and supported at least by current versions of `ifort` and `gfortran`. See [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What is the benefit of the implicit loop over the partial array in the previous answer?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt no difference here, since real() can take a vector or scalar argument.

Comment: Implied do in I/O is sometimes slower than array subsections https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/b10932b4-0edd-4e61-89f2-6e478ccba9aa/entry/improving_i_o_performance_in_xl_fortran3?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

`ifort` uses a default record length of `80`. Everything beyond that is put on the next line. You can extend that at runtime by issueing `export FORT_FMT_RECL=250`, which extends that to 250 characters. (You need to adjust that number, of course).

But my guess would be the format specifier of your write statement. Did you try writing the matrix row-by-row instead of element-wise? Then you could directly specify the number of elements (instead of using `advance='no'`).

[This post](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/269493) might be helpful as well!

EDIT:
Writing row-by-row could be realized like this:

```
open(unit=2, file='graph1.txt', ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
do i=1,N
  write(2,*) real( Vec(i,:) ) 
end do
close(2)
```

Comment: I'm fresh in ifort so I didn't really get your idea. where should I append this sentence "export FORT_FMT_RECL=250"? in my code?

Comment: Oh, that's something you specify at runtime - so just call your program like `export FORT_FMT_RECL=250; ./a.out` or `FORT_FMT_RECL=250 ./a.out`.

Comment: got it. Thank you. Still I'm wondering how to decide the RECL number. Is it some times of the colume number? I set N=500 and M=1500 and run like this "FORT_FMT_RECL=3000 ./a.out" but get a txt file with 2994 lines....Should I also set RECL number in my code?

Comment: I tried as you suggested and seems FORT_FMT_RECL= didn't work. I'm considering your advice "writing matrix row-by-row". could you give more information about this?

Comment: You specify the record length in the open statement, I think the number specified there takes precedence. I added some example code to the answer without an explicit `RECL`. With that, `FORT_FMT_RECL=` should have an impact.

Comment: just incidentally gfortran (4.1) seems to never line wrap a single list directed  write statement regardles of (or without) recl. Setting recl too small for the entire write to fit on one line causes a runtine error.