# Fortran, How to change the write record size?

Tags: fortran

I am attempting to write some integer values out to a file. Each "list" of integers must be on the same line. The values come from a variety of locations in the code, and so instead of
placing all the values into yet another array, I thought I would just output them one at a time using the `advance='NO'` setting. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
open(unit=120,file=mesh_name,action='WRITE',iostat=io,status='REPLACE',recl=(nsp*9+10))

    write(120,*) nTri,nNode,2,nEdgeBd

    if (o > 1) then

        do t = 1,nTri
            write(120,'(i2,3i9)',advance = 'NO') o,tri(:,t)-1

            en = triEdge(1,t)
            write(120,'(i9)',advance = 'NO') (edgeA(i,en)-1, i=2,o)
            en = triEdge(2,t)
            write(120,'(i9)',advance = 'NO') (edgeA(i,en)-1, i=2,o)
            en = triEdge(2,t)
            write(120,'(i9)',advance = 'NO') (edgeA(i,en)-1, i=2,o)

            if (o > 2) write(120,'(i9)',advance = 'NO') (triInt(i,t)-1, i=1,nIntNode)
            write(120,*)
        end do
```

When the number of values is small, it outputs correctly as:

```
   3984        8052           2          84
 2     1443     1368     1431     2034     2035     2035
 2     1358     1261     1290     2037     2038     2038
 2       97       13       14     2040     2041     2041
 2     1291     1272     1273     2043     2044     2044
```

However, when each list gets longer, it outputs as follows:

```
      3984       18054           2          84
 3     1443     1368     1431     2034
     2035     2036
     2037     2036
     2037    14070
 3     1358     1261     1290     2040
     2041     2042
     2043     2042
     2043    14071
 3       97       13       14     2046
```

As you can see, I've attempted to change the default record length with the `recl` parameter in the `open` statement.

I'm using gfortran 4.7.3.

So my question is: What am I not understanding about how fortran deals with the io here?

Comment: your i9 needs a repeat specifier..see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843480/how-to-write-a-huge-matrix-to-file-row-by-row-fortran-90/18849983#18849983

Comment: @george Thanks for finding that link. Using some info there I ended up finding [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/07/01/doctor-fortran-in-revert-revert-the-end-of-the-format-is-nigh) which explains why.