# Write complex output in .txt file

Tags: io, format, fortran

I'm trying to write a Matrix with complex entries in a .txt file, but it does not work. Here is my Code:

```
MODULE Derivation
    IMPLICIT NONE
    TYPE :: DensOp
    COMPLEX , DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: MatrixElem
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(2) :: MatrixDim
    COMPLEX :: MatTrace, MatDet
    END TYPE


SUBROUTINE WriteOnFile(A)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    TYPE(DensOP), INTENT(IN) :: A

    ...
    ...
    INTEGER :: ii
    OPEN(UNIT=39, ACTION='WRITE', FILE='Output.txt', STATUS='REPLACE')
    DO  ii=1, A%MatrixDim(1)
            WRITE(39,100) A%MatrixElem(ii,:)
            100 FORMAT(' ',F5.3, SP, F5.3, "i")
    END DO
    ...
    CLOSE(39)
END SUBROUTINE

end module

PROGRAM DerivedTypes
    USE Derivation
    IMPLICIT NONE
    TYPE (DensOp) :: A
    COMPLEX :: test
    test=0.0e0

    WRITE(*,100) test
    100 FORMAT(F5.3,SP ,F5.3, "i")
    A=initdensop(3,5)
    A%MatrixElem=(3.0e0, 5.0e0)
    Call WriteOnFile(A)

END PROGRAM DerivedTypes
```

The Output that I obtain Looks like this

```
 3.000*****i
 **********i
 **********i
 **********i
 **********i
 3.000*****i
 **********i
 **********i
 **********i
 **********i
 3.000*****i
 **********i
 **********i
 **********i
 **********i
```

Can anybody explain me why this does not work as it is supposed to work? I tried it with the variable test and checked if it should actually work and in the case of the variable check it works perfectly. So I do not really know what mistake I am making right now?

Comment: Generally Fortran writes `*`s when the output fields you've specified for numeric output aren't wide enough for the numbers (and don't forget the space you might need for a `-` sign).  Try replacing `f5.3` with `f8.3` or whatever is adequate.

Comment: Ok, now I can at least see the numbers, but still the entries of the Matrix are printed one above another, i.e. 3.000  +5.000i
   +3.000  +5.000i !new line                   
   +3.000  +5.000i !new line
   +3.000  +5.000i !new line
   +3.000  +5.000i !new line
    3.000  +5.000i !new line
   +3.000  +5.000i !new line
   +3.000  +5.000i !new line
   +3.000  +5.000i !new line
   +3.000  +5.000i !new line

Comment: You need to use a format for the whole line, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843480/how-to-write-a-huge-matrix-to-file-row-by-row-fortran-90 Try something like omething like `'(*( ' ',F8.3, SP, F8.3, "i"))'`